# error occurs when trying to build pintool with make

Tags: makefile, cygwin, gnu-make, intel-pin

OS : windows 10

Intel Pin version : pin-3.28 msvc

visual studio version : visual studio 2022 conmmunity

cygwin 2.926, GNU make 4.4

i was try to use make for building mypintool.dll
but make is following error occurs.

```
mkdir -p obj-intel64/
C:/w64devkit-1.19.0/w64devkit/bin/make.exe objects
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'objects'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-m
svc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
C:/w64devkit-1.19.0/w64devkit/bin/make.exe libs
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-
msvc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'libs'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-m
svc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
C:/w64devkit-1.19.0/w64devkit/bin/make.exe dlls
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-
msvc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'dlls'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-m
svc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
C:/w64devkit-1.19.0/w64devkit/bin/make.exe apps
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-
msvc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'apps'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-m
svc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
C:/w64devkit-1.19.0/w64devkit/bin/make.exe tools
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-
msvc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
cl /EHs- /EHa- /wd4530 /DTARGET_WINDOWS /nologo /Gy  /Oi- /GR- /GS- /DPIN_CRT=1
/D_WINDOWS_H_PATH_="" /D__LP64__ /Zc:threadSafeInit- /Zc:sizedDealloc- /DTARGET_
IA32E /DHOST_IA32E /I../../../source/include/pin /I../../../source/include/pin/g
en -I../../../extras/stlport/include -I../../../extras -I../../../extras/libstdc
++/include -I../../../extras/crt/include -I../../../extras/crt -I../../../extras
/crt/include/arch-x86_64 -I../../../extras/crt/include/kernel/uapi -I../../../ex
tras/crt/include/kernel/uapi/asm-x86 /FIinclude/msvc_compat.h /I../../../extras/
components/include /I../../../extras/xed-intel64/include/xed /I../../../source/t
ools/Utils /I../../../source/tools/InstLib /MD /O2  /c /Foobj-intel64/MyPinTool.
obj MyPinTool.cpp
MyPinTool.cpp
../../../source/include/pin/gen\pinsync.hpp(105): warning C5208: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes
../../../source/include/pin/gen\pinsync.hpp(238): warning C5208: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes
../../../source/include/pin/gen\pinsync.hpp(842): warning C5208: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes
link /DLL /EXPORT:main /NODEFAULTLIB /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /IGNORE:4210 /IGNOR
E:4049 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT ../../../intel64/runtime/pincrt/crtbeginS.obj /MAC
HINE:x64 /ENTRY:Ptrace_DllMainCRTStartup /OPT:REF  /out:obj-intel64/MyPinTool.dl
l obj-intel64/MyPinTool.obj /LIBPATH:../../../intel64/lib /LIBPATH:../../../inte
l64/lib-ext /LIBPATH:../../../intel64/runtime/pincrt /LIBPATH:../../../extras/xe
d-intel64/lib pin.lib xed.lib pinipc.lib pincrt.lib kernel32.lib
link: extra operand ‘/NODEFAULTLIB’
Try 'link --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [../../../source/tools/Config/makefile.default.rules:241: obj-intel
64/MyPinTool.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/llder/Downloads/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-m
svc-windows/pin-3.28-98749-g6643ecee5-msvc-windows/source/tools/MyPinTool'
make: *** [../Config/makefile.config:373: all] Error 2
```

I registered the bin directory of Microsoft Visual Studio where cl and link are located as environmental variables.

when i build MyPinTool from visual studio i was succeed build
I want to know why it's not possible only in make
and i want to know how to fix it